# Regular expressions: distinguish strings including/excluding a given word

Tags: python, regex

I'm working in Python and try to handle StatsModel's GLM output. I'm relatively new to regular expressions.
I have strings such as

```
string_1 = "C(State)[T.Kansas]"
string_2 = "C(State, Treatment('Alaska'))[T.Kansas]"
```

I wrote the following regex:

```
pattern = re.compile('C\((.+?)\)\[T\.(.+?)\]') 
print(pattern.search(string_1).group(1))
#State
print(pattern.search(string_2).group(1))
#State, Treatment('Alaska')
```

So both of these strings match the pattern. But we want to get `State` in both cases. Basically we want to get read of everything after comma (including it) inside first brackets.

How can we distinguish the `string_2` pattern from `string_1`'s and extract only `State` without `, Treatment`?

Comment: Please also include a literal example of your desired output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add an optional non-capturing group instead of just allowing all characters:

```
pattern = re.compile('C\((.+?)(?:, .+?)?\)\[T\.(.+?)\]')
```

`(?:...)` groups the contents together without capturing it. The trailing `?` makes the group optional.

Answer (score 3):

You may use this regex using negative character classes:

```
C\((\w+)[^[]*\[T\.([^]]+)\]
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/RIGmGb/1)

Comment: Thank you for your answer and link. However Mad Physicist's a bit more straightforwarded answer seems to work more desirable in "extreme" cases (which I obviously didn't mention).